# Insert and read nsdata in swift to make http post

Tags: swift, sqlite, swift2, http-post, nsdata

I'm making an app that connects to a server that manages information in php.

Through the app I upload images to the server , which then treatment in php. The problem is that the file upload takes too long , so I want to add the body of the post request containing the parameters and image, in the SQLite database .

Once this inserted into the database , when you reopen the application, checks the database if there is information to upload to the server, if so, in the background raises the image , so it does not slow down or the user finds

The problem is that not get it to work the post request .

The column of the table I have put both BLOB and TEXT, but when making the request POST, I get empty when I will deal with PHP from the server

The body of the POST request is NSData , to obtain it from the database and make the request I do so:

```
var body = resultadosSql.dataForColumn("body")
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: stringUrl)!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
let boundary = self.generateBoundaryString()

request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.HTTPBody = body

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in

       if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
       }
       print("***** data = \(data)") 
       print("***** request = \(request)")

       // You can print out response object
       print("******* response = \(response)")

       // Print out reponse body
       let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
       print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            print("COOOOOOOORRRECT!!!!!!!!")
            GestorDB.updateEstadoFiles(idArchivo)
       })
   }
   task.resume()
```

The response is:

```
***** data = Optional(<>)
***** request = <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x1373c4e50> { URL: http://url_a_la_que_llamo.com }
******* response = Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x135df59b0> { URL: http://url_a_la_que_llamo.com } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 20;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Mon, 22 Aug 2016 09:29:16 GMT";
    Server = Apache;
    "Set-Cookie" = "720plan=R1726338592; path=/; expires=Mon, 22-Aug-2016 10:41:58 GMT";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.2.17";
} })
****** response data =
```

In the database the body is:

```
--Boundary-D1CF4360-B758-48DF-8AB4-FCB4F3A2AFCD
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="data_notice_add"

dGl0dWxvPVZHVnpkQ0JwYm5ObGNuUWdibTkwYVdOcFlRPT0qLyp0aXRsZT1URzl5WlcwZ2FYQnpkVzBnWkc5c2IzSWdjMmwwSUdGdFpYUT0qLypjb250ZW5pZG89VTJsdVpzT3RiaUJGZDJkbGNtaHlkR29nZDJWbmFIVjNaWEpvSUdScFoyNWhjaUJ4ZFdWa1lXNGdZMlVnWldnZ2FtVT0qLypoYXNoPU9URXlNRE01TkRreCovKmxpbms9WkdabmFtND0qLyp0ZWxlZm9ubz1PVFl6TkRVeU1UUTMqLypjb2RpZ289UmpGRE1USTJRVEl0TWpKR05pMDBOamcyTFRnMlF6WXRRakJHUmpVMlJqUXlNamRHKi8qYXBwPU1RPT0=
--Boundary-D1CF4360-B758-48DF-8AB4-FCB4F3A2AFCD
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="imagenNoticia"; filename="F1C126A2-22F6-4686-86C6-B0FF56F4227F-22-10-32.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpg

   /*HERE BUT it APPEARS coded picture is very long to add , I ADD ONLY THE BEGINNING*/

ÿØÿà JFIF   H H  ÿá XExif  MM *           ‡i       &                    ô       N    ÿí 8Photoshop 3.0 8BIM      8BIM%     ÔŒÙ ²é€  ˜ìøB~ÿÀ Nô ÿÄ               
ÿÄ µ   } !1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ            
ÿÄ µ  w !1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á   #3RðbrÑ
$4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÛ C ÿÛ CÿÝ  ?ÿÚ   ? þà¬íö…ãùûÿ »îqß¹Šû
µ/x¥¾îéÞþJöþ¶Õ,cÊ’þ¼»ôïë¦Æü)·žßý×¿<ôé–ã›éý/óûþò¿¯ëúüÑ=fPÄIöˆÆ?ÏéøVœ«–÷}zvÿ ·—å÷g#üÿ ‘ÄþU1½î•íý_ð i|vãëƒù|Äß>ù=UwÒß×ü0zÏÿ µÓ9–â’ ¢I ž9!š@xåŠU)$R!@$F(êN
’rhjútzá§Æ‹ð›Å:?ƒ|e7“à/_[é?
<arOÙtmv`Vßá§Š¯[äµšè/üPzÕáHµtxvæQªÚX¶¥Èë{
°¥U·
²å¡Uè¹ºQ“»Jo_gt½¢Ñ7R>ýüoEf·íëm÷ßT•ú\÷68à¨>¹Æ$rPG^0>íu3åöçéýzÿ ŸJ aÙøþ=}±úþY¦¯²¾½[yu·˜2¡ì1è{òÎkU*¾4¿-þakïêDè˜÷ü¾¼î'ê1Œ÷<nÚ.Ouùöé¶Ÿ+ù+û¡Y Œó´gÜgéÀ?ËŽk^iwõOó#ÙÃ²+5´g§ùÿ _Æ©Mß[[ï×ÿ ^_Ó¼p•$žÏoþÚ?—Ýö¡{oLýsüð9öâ­Mi®¾–üLÝ7äÿ ýº_×³Qí‡ ¨Îzû÷î{ätü±Zs?UÙ»£7ío×óýooãVKEê3’?ÏONr=¸v‘ªÖ?¹$×Þï»±¶û¶·þLÿ »ùd²#<g?^ÿ ˜ã>‹S[F¦‰ëäöÛ­¹_þ•÷^Ñuòþ¼¿­uØ£%¡÷üt~¸út­•[ím4}>ü¾íŒý”ôz¿O»úüÊÍlÃ¶\zóòööïŽ1óZŸ}?ý¶?×k%,öe]?Gúmn·+´;~<Ÿëý9ìxÅRiíý~ð<¶3p’Ý=¯ÞÉuvþ»ìBcn„Ÿ¡þ¸þ¬Èþ¿¯ëò#({ôéŽÃ€G÷s‚8ã‘ŽF>`    ÎIúöýzþ€ú“Ÿ˜ô 2œÇ=úñùÿ <bëúþ¿1ÙÚövïÓúþºä9õôëô îçò_LÕEÙïoËô¶Ëþ¨¨´ºÛ¿ŸÏ[yþ›”ÙŽpüHúuÝøtöÆ0»&º?¹SJü­¤ïuº×nÛt×[ô±J[r:Ž™Æ?SŽžãÓ½Z¨üŸÎßûl¼ºýÿ g7CM%æ•´ôêþvûìd\AŸ”äzwóíëìÝP•÷þ½|ÿ ð/ñ74£}:§ÛåüËó}ºÜÉ’##ïõôôÇ®F™­koëüÿ ®æ-[B¤‘‚=ðIÏÏ¿<ðqß§NMi¦¬Þ¾ŸÕ¿þQç©M»µ«¿d´ü.üÝßO2“Äyù{sìztÂ÷£#ðZkÛúóü¾óGtÕ•þ]ßoŸ©JHÏ¦zþ_™Çâ{ö­Ó¿ü=ÿ Ëòû¬OõýÀ)ºg>žÝ¿ñáŸËn´À©$gúz¡úŒñŽã®ÿ ¯/Ïî(I9ÿ =8lúúÛ§u§ã¯õýoe)bâûyÿ _äW#Ïãøÿ Nôÿ ¯ëúü‰ hœç#žÄsï“ÿ Ím®)+]%mÿ à.¾¿›_òþ¿®èÎš<gŒŸo¨ÆxçŽUÏ;¾^ˆ¾d­uuäž××Ë·[kgËœÓzô]:ÿ _ÊÞö{§^Üñß×Ý};ŸË'uÅÙ®Ýu·õOW9²–©ÿ •ÿ Ëúï±U£#žŸ×ñïœ÷yÍl¤žÏð·õ¿õs·_ÿ ­¿«²ãÇãà1×úŽŒÄBÙÉÏ×þ¹ü?‡?Žh£“Ï~ž{gð'>ø 
Í»×¸ü:} ÇãíŒPIWp ƒŒœœ=ýyü   <öË×õ¿ôúl'¯»­žïeé¯gÙÙÛ©IÆAž§ðÁëž2u­¢’Z[ÎÝú˜»ßVÝ´×}?¯ò*ºîëÏ¯çß×ùÈê•¡˜†GŸ×ñ8õÆöZ“~—Jþoúï·Õ µ-Ó ØcõÇ\ôüñ…ÎSkgù>êþ‰éº½ü½í}“ÒûZîÚßç§.žOÉ•¦µHÏúöôõäœ~!hUUÕêŸãnO.œß¨JkEg®Í´ûo-?;Ý(ãOŒàËÜŽÍß÷zúîÞ2wò}’·¯EÛ×Ïc*X‹vÏåêNzûã^yJVÉÛúþ¯èD¢å¶ßê»÷õ½‘ØÛvHïŒõ÷î íÏ°Å®ŠÛù5ùY[äÝü¬W±’ÖIÙÙ/;íÝë­´ûîãdª¿tûŸNýpaœVN¤›½ÞúyÃ­ìôóLßØ5ßÞ²÷m{ÛK-úÃ½³'„+”gùôïþA«Œ¯ªÓçÿ 
~mLškt×ªkþõêQ0qèqŒç8è}€éìNj¥.¯oËñIïm#÷/†b¶²³vVÿ ƒÖÿ ðä‚Ô ¨ ç=ÿ ¦sô>ü`
ÅÍßMµü~ZÛ§îîvF”R÷•ß]ÿ «ÛGo^§9©éJË!?LŽù#×¸üÝ­éVi¥kßâÛ§^÷Û§Ýc’®Úú^úI~ »-×¶›«êx‰~xkUÕ$»Ôt{;›“!–X¾Å,UI*Ç ±êxéÏðú´±2ŒMÚï¥ÿ )Gòû¾Öj¥jiF59Rè•Ö»µ½µéwßKÚ?ÿÐþäÚHl3vwÂÆì±ÈN9åãìåò<¹$"o‘\¢¿ÓJw½·¾ýïÙym¥íøÇÉQ”®ÿ §éª½ºÙ;]^ÖFàA€qÁ ƒë‘ÁÜr1‘îzÖ%{)r§¦½/¯èºw¿“côãê3ùËü¿/â  ä—òËî‘—óóëéÏ_÷º~=þ»­JÊÖ¿õþù¯Âä’˜ýÇ¿ýŸøýñ
I5îüÓ·èÿ /ºà5¢ãü~ž=N0*”ãçóý¢üþûõýmýw½ÈŒd{}Gÿ d;{š«§³_}ÿ ¯ë°
(ÃßéÇþÌÙÿ =sò°9Ox'Ã<)®ø#Æš=¾»áéòéºÆ•u½RæÚ\x¦’âÒòÖUŽêÂþÖH®ì/

    --Boundary-D1CF4360-B758-48DF-8AB4-FCB4F3A2AFCD--
```

I have several questions of which may be the problem :

- When saving to the database as NSData not saved well
- When reading from the database as NSData does not read well
- When performing the POST request did not perform well

Thanks

Comment: can you give us some more specific code?

Comment: I modified my question @UlfGjerdingen